# Undefined index in the Slim Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, slim

I have an error in my code that does not identify the desphoto element which is a way to find a photo.

[image: err]
<img src="" alt="">

This is the code where the desphoto is called `<img src="{$value.desphoto}" alt="">` the code I passed is the error that happens in the cache directory of my view-cache, only my question is because it is like value1 and not just value.
Look at its value in the view-cache: `<?php $counter1=-1; if( isset($products) && ( is_array($products) || $products instanceof Traversable ) && sizeof($products) ) foreach( $products as $key1 => $value1 ){ $counter1++; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

If you have copy-pasted that code, you'll want to fix the syntax and see what's going on there. The closing brace for the `foreach` is missing.

Additionally, I have changed `sizeof` to `count` as `sizeof` is an alias and may be deprecated in the future, so best to not rely on it.

I've also removed the `foreach`  as it seems it was doing the same operation. Keep it if you're doing more.

```
<?php 
$counter1=-1; 
if( 
    isset($products) && ( 
        is_array($products) || 
        $products instanceof Traversable 
    ) && 
    count($products) 
) 
    $counter1+=count($products);
?>
```